# Parent Publication option is not shwoing

Tags: tridion

I am not able to add parent publication.I have create the the blank publication and create the root structure group. after that i want to inherit with my parent publication but no option is coming when i open the blur printing. Only child publication option is coming and disabled.

Comment: Hi Shekhar. You might want to ask this over at the Tridion Stack Exchange site: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the root structure group before being able to set it as a parent